# Multiples cifs shares with noauto on same mountpoint only works with root

Tags: samba, fstab, cifs

I have these entries in /etc/fstab

```
//server1/share /mnt/folder cifs rw,uid=1001,user,noauto,username=user,password=password 0 0
//server2/share /mnt/folder cifs rw,uid=1001,user,noauto,username=user,password=password 0 0
```

As root, I can mount and umout any of those shares to my local folder with

```
mount //server1/share 
mount //server2/share
```

But as a user I can only mount the first share (//server1/share) on the second I get

```
mount //server2/share
mount.cifs: permission denied: no match for /mnt/folder found in /etc/fstab
```

If it failed both with root or the user I'd assume that mount.cifs is not capable of handling this, but as root user it works just fine.
I've found some stackoverflow questions about the mountall command but I think that's an unrelated issue

Any ideas?